ffmpeg image slideshow timing not consistent
What is the right set of parameters to make all images show for 10 seconds in a slideshow made with ffmpeg?
Using this command on Windows 10 with:
ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
ffmpeg -f concat -r 1/10 -i listimages.txt -crf 10 -vf fps=8,format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 imageslides.mp4 -y

Some of the images are showing for 10 seconds as needed, and others are staying visible for over a minute. There are 150 jpg files all the same resolution 1600x1200.
Thanks.

Post your own question, sometimes get your own answer. There were images in the file listing that were not consumable by ffmpeg and I did not understand that they were choking, and because it still output the file I thought everything "worked". Displaying the file list in Windows Explorer and including the resolution attributes and EXIF data gave me clues about the problem files.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
